# Grouping inserting strings

Tags: r, grouping

I have a dataframe called Teachers:

```
Teachers <- data.frame(Name = c("Mark","Mark","Peter","Richard","Clay","Clay"),
                       Pos  = c("Coord","Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher","Coord","Teacher"))
```

Are there any R basic commands that would produce the following group data.frame?:

```
Teachers2 <- data.frame(Name = c("Mark","Peter","Richard","Clay"),
                        Pos  = c("Coord/Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher","Coord/Teacher"))
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `aggregate(Pos ~ Name, data = Teachers, paste, collapse = "/")`. The row order is different.

Comment: tks, Will try this

Comment: It worked Rui, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paste` should do it:

```
library(tidyverse)
Teachers2 <- Teachers %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    summarise(Pos=paste(Pos,collapse="/"))
```

Output:

```
     Name           Pos
1    Mark Coord/Teacher
2   Peter       Teacher
3 Richard       Teacher
4    Clay Coord/Teacher
```