# Aggregate Inserting Strings

Tags: r, grouping

I have a Dataframe called teachers:

```
Teachers <- data.frame(Discipline = c("Math","Math","Chem","Arts","History","History"),
                       Teacher = c("Mark","Mark","Peter","Richard","Mark","Mark"),
                       Position  = c("Coord","Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher","Coord","Teacher"))
```

In this case Mark is Coord/Teacher in two disciplines. How can I, using basic R commands, get an output like this:

```
Teachers2 <- data.frame(Discipline = c("Math","Chem","Arts","History"),
                        Teacher = c("Mark","Peter","Richard","Mark"),
                        Position  = c("Coord/Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher","Coord/Teacher"))
```

I did a similar grouping with some help at [Grouping inserting strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534419/grouping-inserting-strings)

Thanks for your Help

Comment: do you accept `dplyr` solution?

Comment: Yes, no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base `R` solution using the [`aggregate`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html) function:

```
aggregate(Position ~ Discipline + Teacher, data = Teachers, 
          function(x) paste0(x, collapse = '/'))

#   Discipline Teacher      Position
# 1    History    Mark Coord/Teacher
# 2       Math    Mark Coord/Teacher
# 3       Chem   Peter       Teacher
# 4       Arts Richard       Teacher
```

Or equivalently (HT @h3rm4n):

```
aggregate(Position ~ Discipline + Teacher, data = Teachers, 
          paste0, collapse = '/')

#   Discipline Teacher      Position
# 1    History    Mark Coord/Teacher
# 2       Math    Mark Coord/Teacher
# 3       Chem   Peter       Teacher
# 4       Arts Richard       Teacher
```

Comment: you could also use it in the form `aggregate(Position ~ Discipline + Teacher, Teachers, paste0, collapse = '/')` (I've removed it from my answer as you posted your answer while I was updating mine)

Comment: That´s what I meant, bouncyball, Tks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
library(dplyr)
Teachers %>% 
  group_by(Teacher, Discipline) %>% 
  summarise(Position = paste0(Position, collapse = '/'))
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Teacher [?]
  Teacher Discipline      Position
   <fctr>     <fctr>         <chr>
1    Mark    History Coord/Teacher
2    Mark       Math Coord/Teacher
3   Peter       Chem       Teacher
4 Richard       Arts       Teacher
```

---

Another option which might be worth to consider:

```
Teachers %>% 
  group_by(Teacher) %>% 
  summarise(Discipline = paste0(unique(Discipline), collapse = '/'),
            Position = paste0(unique(Position), collapse = '/'))
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Teacher   Discipline      Position
   <fctr>        <chr>         <chr>
1    Mark Math/History Coord/Teacher
2   Peter         Chem       Teacher
3 Richard         Arts       Teacher
```

Comment: If I want discipline to not be unique, How It would be? I´ll use it after to merge with other Dataframe.

Comment: That would return the Data Frame :

Comment: @Malakias I removed the `unique`-function from the first solution. You can use the output of the first to merge with another dataframe.

Comment: Ok, I´ll try it, tks